# Comparing word to dictionary and assigning value

Tags: python, nlp

I used scrapy to crawl several bullying forums and used the results as a dictionary.

What I'm trying to do now is extracting the keywords of a sentence, e.g. `He harassed me in the chat`, which would give the keywords `Harassed` and `chat`, and comparing these keywords to my dictionary of words and assigning a value to how relevant it is (which in this case would obviously provide a high value close to 1.0 since it is extremely relevant to bullying).

I've gotten the keyword extraction down, so right now I just need know how I can do the comparison.

I've taken a look at using `pandas`, `scikit` and `nltk` but they seem to work best for dictionaries with multiple fields, whereas I only have a bag of words.

Is there some NLP library out there that does this for me? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy or in the standard library there's regex: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A problem I foresee with this is its just attempting to match strings based on the spelling/similar letters of the words. This could be an issue if for example "harassed" isn't in my dictionary, yet it is relevant. Is there any library out there more machine-learning oriented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, I think that computing semantic similarity measure is the solution is what you are looking for. Semantic similarity is a scalar value reporting distance between words (or other linguistic units) based on the likeness of their meaning (you could actually call it relevance). E.g. for words `harassment` and `bullying` such value would be high, while for words `harassment` and `programming` it would be low.

There are different ways to compute semantic similarity. One of the simplest ones based on distance in `WordNet` graph structure. It is implemented in `NLTK`. Some toy examples could be fount at [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

More effective methods based on machine learning and corpus statistics are called distributional semantic models (`Word2Vec` is the most ubiquitous one). They represent words with real-valued vectors, and compute similarity between words as a distance between corresponding vectors. Install `gensim`, download a pre-trained distributional semantic model (for instance, from [here](http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/)), and you will be able to compute similarity value for words ([gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) should help).

Finally, if you are able to compute a similarity value for a pair words, you can set a heuristic threshold for similarity value when you will be seeking through you dictionary. If the similarity for a suspended word from a sentence will be lower than the threshold for all words in you dictionary, then, probably, it will not be related to harassment. You could also experiment with other measures, e.g. consider word vectors from you dictionary as a cluster, and compute similarity to the centroid of the cluster.